# Set focus to a window using xprop

Tags: linux, x11, emacs, gnome-shell

I'm using the following to remove the windows border in my emacs when it starts up (--fullscreen is not an option as it also covers gnome shell's taskbar).

```
xprop -f -id xid _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS '0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0'" 
# xid is my emacs window
```

This works ok, however the window loses focus when I do so.

Considering I know the window id, is there a way to focus on it using xprop or any other builtin commands?  (without installing anything, eg. xdotool or wmctrl)

Comment: The window manager (WM) handles the focus, so you either need some tool like `xdotool` or `wmctrl` that talks to the window manager, or you need to configure your WM directly to assume the correct configuration without using `xprop` (you didn't tell us what WM you are using), or you need some other way to work around what your WM does when you use `xprop`.

Comment: I'm using gnome shell. I'm going to focus my searches around it, thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question with additional information; the comments may go away at some time.